# Angular Unit testing : can't change the reporter of karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying to use the JUnit reporter with karma.

When I launch

```
$ ng test --watch=false --code-coverage
```

It always outputs me

```
10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active01 06 2017 11:57:51.797:ERROR 
[reporter]: Can not load reporter "coverage-istanbul", it is not registered!
```

The problem is, in my `karma.conf.json` I have no reference to istanbul :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      // require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'coverage', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      outputFile: 'test-report.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage ?
      ['mocha', 'junit'] :
      ['mocha'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS',
      // 'Chrome'
    ],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Do you have any idea where it might come from ?

I also deleted all packages refering to istanbul in my `package.json` file, I also used `npm prune` just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I wrote an issue on the Angular CLI project and they told me that using the `code coverage` option automatically adds the istanbul package, no matter what you have set up. The command I use is now

```
ng test --reporters=junit --watch=false || ECHO
```

Answer (score 0):

The right package to install to get rid of the above error is:

karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter

`npm install karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter --save-dev`